# Tag cloud of only specific posts in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable

Hi i am using  acts_as_taggable in my rails app 2.3.11.

I have model User who can  posts which has tags associated .
So i am using like

```
@tags = User.find(:first).posts.tag_counts
```

to get the tags which will display using tag_cloud

Now the issue is , we have some feature which remove the some of the posts of the User based on some condition on the post type , NOW how can i get the tags of only those posts .
The posts that i wanted i am keeping in @posts . But how to use the same ..

Please give some suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Define a scope in post that defines the conditions based on the post type. Since, you have not mentioned the exact criteria..

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :specific_type, <?> #fill in with conditions for type of post
end

User.find(:first).posts.specific_type.tag_counts
```